# Everything in Word looks like it is in header/footer view

Tags: microsoft-word

So I downloaded some word document from the internet. For some reason, every word in Word is foggy, but when I am trying to print it or open it in another software, it is perfectly normal. I assume it is because some setting that I misconfigrured  [image] but I don't seem to be able to get Word to work the way it should be. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is Office for mac updated to the newest?

If your machine uses a Retina display, please try following steps to have a check.

- Quit the Word for mac.
- Open the Applications folder.
- Click the Word app once to select it, then choose Get Info from the File
  menu.
- From the Get Info window that opens, select the checkbox labeled
  "Open in Low Resolution".
- Close the Get Info window and open Word app again.